# "Standard methods of the calculus of variations" or "Do you read German?"

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, spline

I'm trying to understand an [article of Reinsch (1967)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3d59/0e6f0fdf32dbd1aece65b9b9fc58953d5890.pdf), on smoothing spline functions. The author uses some rules that unfortunately I couldn't find.

The minimized functional is:
$$
\int_{x_0}^{x_n} g''(x)^2 dx + p \left\lbrace \sum_{i=0}^n\left(\frac{g(x_i)-y_i}{\delta y_i}\right)^2 + z^2 -S \right\rbrace
$$

With this, the author deduces that:
$$
\forall i,\ f^{(3)}(x_i)_{-} - f^{(3)}(x_i)_{+} = 2p \frac{f(x_i)-y_i}{\delta y_i}
$$
where $f^{(3)}$ is undefined in each $x_i$, $f^{(3)}(x_i)_{-}$ is the inferior limit in $x_i$, and $f^{(3)}(x_i)_{+}$ the superior limit.

This is the point I don't get. I understand how to compute the derivative of a functional when it is formulated as an integral, but this one isn't. I guess there is some rules I missed.

The author cite a book (Variationsrechnung und ihre Anwendung in Physik und Technik, Funk, 1962), but unfortunately I can't read German, and I couldn't find any source to corroborate Reinsch in his reasoning.

What is the derivation rule I missed? Is there a source (in English or in French) to corroborate the author computation?

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably note that Reinsch specifically deduces that condition by considering the Euler-Lagrange equations and you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the functional
 $$
F(g)=\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{n}}(g^{\prime\prime}(x))^{2}dx+p\sum_{i=0}^{n}\left(
\frac{g(x_{i})-y_{i}}{\delta y_{i}}\right)  ^{2}
 $$
and let $f$ be a minimum over all function $g\in C^{2}([x_{0},x_{n}])$. Then
taking $f+th$, for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $h\in C^{2}([x_{0},x_{n}])$, you have
that
 $$
F(f+th)\geq F(f)
 $$
and so the one variable function $k(t)=F(f+th)$ has a minimum at $t=0$. Hence,
$k^{\prime}(0)=0$. So if we now differentiate under the integral sign, we get
\begin{align*}
k^{\prime}(t)  & =\frac{d}{dt}(F(f+ht))=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{n}
}(f^{\prime\prime}(x)+th^{\prime\prime}(x))^{2}dx\\&\quad+p\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i=0}
^{n}\left(  \frac{f(x_{i})+th(x_{i})-y_{i}}{\delta y_{i}}\right)  ^{2}\\
& =\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{n}}2(f^{\prime\prime}(x)+th^{\prime\prime}(x))h^{\prime
\prime}(x)\,dx\\&\quad+2p\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(f(x_{i})+th(x_{i})-y_{i})h(x_{i}
)}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Taking $t=0$ gives
 $$
0=k^{\prime}(0)=\int_{x_{0}}^{x_{n}}2f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime
}(x)\,dx+2p\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{(f(x_{i})-y_{i})h(x_{i})}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}.
 $$
This is true for all $h\in C^{2}([x_{0},x_{n}])$. We now play with $h$. Fix
$i$ and consider functions $h$ which are zero except on $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$.
Then
 $$
0=\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i}}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime}(x)\,dx.
 $$
By Weyl's lemma, this implies that $f^{\prime\prime}$ has two derivatives in
$(x_{i-1},x_{i})$ and that $f^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}(x)=0$ in each
interval $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$. Thus, $f^{\prime\prime\prime}$ is constant in each
interval $(x_{i-1},x_{i})$ but can jump at each $x_{i}$. To find the
constants, fix $1<i<n$ and take $h\in C^{4}([x_{0},x_{n}])$ which is zero outside
of $(x_{i}-\delta,x_{i}+\delta)$, where $\delta<\min\{x_{i}-x_{i-1}%
,x_{i+1}-x_{i}\}$. Then
\begin{align*}
0  & =\int_{x_{i}-\delta}^{x_{i}+\delta}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime
}(x)\,dx+p\frac{(f(x_{i})-y_{i})h(x_{i})}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}\\
& =\int_{x_{i}-\delta}^{x_{i}}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime}
(x)\,dx+\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i}+\delta}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime
}(x)\,dx+p\frac{(f(x_{i})-y_{i})h(x_{i})}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Integrating by parts twice both integrals and using the fact that
$f^{\prime\prime\prime}=0$ in each open interval and that $h$ and its
derivatives up to order 4 are zero at $x_{i}\pm\delta$ we get
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_{i}-\delta}^{x_{i}}&f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime}(x)\,dx  
=-\int_{x_{i}-\delta}^{x_{i}}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime}
(x)\,dx+f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i})h^{\prime}(x_{i})-0\\
& =\int_{x_{i}-\delta}^{x_{i}}f^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}(x)h(x)\,dx+0-f_{-}
^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i})+f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i})h^{\prime}
(x_{i})\\
& =0-f_{-}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i})+f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i}
)h^{\prime}(x_{i}).
\end{align*}
Similarly,
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i}+\delta}&f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime\prime}(x)\,dx  
=-\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i}+\delta}f^{\prime\prime\prime}(x)h^{\prime}
(x)\,dx+0-f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i})h^{\prime}(x_{i})\\
& =\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i}+\delta}f^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}(x)h(x)\,dx-0+f_{+}
^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i})-f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i})h^{\prime}
(x_{i})\\
& =0+f_{+}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i})-f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i}
)h^{\prime}(x_{i}).
\end{align*}
Hence, if we combine the last three equations we get
\begin{align*}
0  & =-f_{-}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i})+f^{\prime\prime}
(x_{i})h^{\prime}(x_{i})+f_{+}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i}
)-f^{\prime\prime}(x_{i})h^{\prime}(x_{i})\\&\quad+2p\frac{(f(x_{i})-y_{i})h(x_{i}
)}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}\\
& =-f_{-}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})h(x_{i})+f_{+}^{\prime\prime\prime}
(x_{i})h(x_{i})+2p\frac{(f(x_{i})-y_{i})h(x_{i})}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Now take $h$ such that $h(x_{i})=1$ and you get
 $$
0=-f_{-}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i})+f_{+}^{\prime\prime\prime}(x_{i}
)+2p\frac{f(x_{i})-y_{i}}{(\delta y_{i})^{2}}.
 $$
For $i=1$ and $i=n$ you do something similar.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!